# Php Listing Data with datatables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a datatable and i am listing 3 columns from database.(Actually got 25)
I have added a submit button for each row and want to see the all data when user click that button on the bottom of the page.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = 
mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<td><button type='submit' value=".$row['id']".">Show Details</a></td>";
            echo "<td>'" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["result"] . "</td>";
        }
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "<p class='lead'><em>No data.</em></p>";
}
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute 
$sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

I tried to use Post method but didn't worked.

Comment: Typo/error in `value=".$row['id']"."`

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you want to know on which line the user clicked on Show Details ??

Comment: Yes i got a text fields on the bottom of the page . If i can get the id value with submit button(or a href etc) i want to list all details.

Comment: You're opening a `button` tag and closing an `a` tag. But this code is missing the client-side component: what happens when someone actually clicks the button. If you want to do it without any JavaScript, then there must be a form, with some kind of input element with a relevant value. You can also add a name to the submit button and it should give you enough info, but you still need a form.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to do it like this.

```
    <?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    // Attempt select query execution

if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,$db))
    die("Cant select to database");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
        if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
        echo "<table id='example'>";
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><button type='submit' value=". $row['id'] . ">Show Details</a></td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["result"] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }
            // Free result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else{
            echo "<p class='lead'><em>No data.</em></p>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute 
    $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    // Close connection

    mysqli_close($db);

    ?>
    <script>
            $('#example').on('click', 'tbody .edit_btn', function () {
                var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),       // Finds the closest row <tr> 
                    $tds = $row.find("td");             // Finds all children <td> elements

                $.each($tds, function() {               // Visits every single <td> element
                    console.log($(this).text());        // Prints out the text within the <td>
                });

            });
    </script>
```